# windows cmd цвет сообщения

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Можно ли задать цвет сообщения, которое я буду выводить в командной строке при помощи `std::cout`, таким образом, чтобы цвет всех предыдущих сообщений не менялся (т.е. разноцветный текст)?

Comment: да, можно - `SetConsoleTextAttribute` меняешь цвет на нужный и перед этим запоминаешь старый цвет, затем выводишь в консоль нужные символы и затем снова вызываешь `SetConsoleTextAttribute` со "старым" цветом.

Comment: Уже разобрался. Для возвращения старого белого цвета надписей достаточно прописать: `SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE);`

Answer (score 1):

Да, это возможно с помощью функции `SetConsoleTextAttribute`:

```
BOOL SetConsoleTextAttribute(HANDLE hConsoleOutput, WORD wAttributes)
```

где:

```
hConsoleOutput — handle окна
wAttributes — набор атрибутов
```

Вот [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682088(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_character_attributes) Вы можете посмотреть сами атрибуты.

В Вашем случае `handle` можно получить вот так:

```
HANDLE hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```